# How to adapt one power point to another power point´s style automatically?

Tags: powerpoint

I have two power points, one is a deck of 40 slides with an outdated style and the other one is a deck of 20 slides with a style I want to copy. Instead of going slide over slide, is there a way in which I can save time?

I already tried copying the slides of the old deck and copying them in the new powerpoint but it doesnt change[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUmBn.png).

Any suggestions? Tool online?

This would be a huge time saver.

Thank you